# Чтение целых чисел из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Допустим в текстовом документе есть такие вот записи:

> 2 34 5 784

Как мне взять эти 4 числа и записать их в 4 разные переменные?
(мне неизвестно будут ли эти числа >10 или > 100 и т.д) 
В паскаль всё просто, но вот с питоном никак не могу разобраться)

Comment: Ну так а в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Как мне взять эти 4 числа и записать их в 4 разные переменнные? То есть: a=2 b=34 c=5 d=789

Comment: Если я просто прочитаю через read или readline, то получиться 2 3 4 5 7 8 4.

Comment: `a, b, c, d = 2, 34, 5, 789`.

Comment: Нет... Мне нужно из файла получить

Comment: И мне неизвестно вообще какие там будут числа. Или 1 2 3 4, или 121 312 45 1

Comment: Да, при чем тут тэг "с" и тэг "работа"?

Comment: Это мой первый вопрос в стэк оверфлоу, вот и затупил. Хотел написать работа с файлами.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = f.read()
r = [int(x) for x in m.split()]
```